# How to control yaw and pitch of mesh in Three.JS?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I've got a mesh whose yaw and pitch I want to be controlled by user input. I naively tried rotating the mesh about the z and y axes, and that seems to control yaw, but up and down is erratic.

```
function checkKeys(keys) {
    if (keys.left) spaceship.rotation.z += .05;
    if (keys.right) spaceship.rotation.z -= .05;
    if (keys.up) spaceship.rotation.y += .05;
    if (keys.down) spaceship.rotation.y -= .05;
}
```

How can I make left/right control the plane's yaw and up/down control pitch?

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordixon/d9BN9/2/

**Update**: I simplified FlyControls.js that wagerfield mentioned so it obeys my gamepad and handles rotation only. Here's what I ended up with (https://gist.github.com/trevordixon/5783321):

```
THREE.FlyControls = function(object) {
    this.object = object;

    // API

    this.movementSpeed = 1.0;
    this.rollSpeed = 0.005;

    // disable default target object behavior

    this.object.useQuaternion = true;

    // internals

    this.tmpQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();

    this.moveState = {up: 0, down: 0, left: 0, right: 0, forward: 0, back: 0, pitchUp: 0, pitchDown: 0, yawLeft: 0, yawRight: 0, rollLeft: 0, rollRight: 0};
    this.moveVector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    this.rotationVector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    this.handleEvent = function(event) {
        if (typeof this[event.type] == 'function') {
            this[event.type](event);
        }
    };

    this.update = function(delta) {
        this.moveState.yawLeft   = -gamepad.axes[2];
        this.moveState.pitchDown =   gamepad.axes[3];

        this.moveState.rollLeft = (Math.abs(gamepad.axes[0]) < 0.15 ? 0 : gamepad.axes[0]) ||
                              gamepad.buttons[15]/2;

        this.moveState.rollRight = (Math.abs(gamepad.axes[1]) < 0.15 ? 0 : gamepad.axes[1]) ||
                               gamepad.buttons[14]/2;

        this.updateRotationVector();

        var moveMult = delta * this.movementSpeed;
        var rotMult = delta * this.rollSpeed;

        this.object.translateX(this.moveVector.x * moveMult);
        this.object.translateY(this.moveVector.y * moveMult);
        this.object.translateZ(this.moveVector.z * moveMult);

        this.tmpQuaternion.set(this.rotationVector.x * rotMult, this.rotationVector.y * rotMult, this.rotationVector.z * rotMult, 1).normalize();
        this.object.quaternion.multiply(this.tmpQuaternion);

        // expose the rotation vector for convenience
        this.object.rotation.setEulerFromQuaternion(this.object.quaternion, this.object.eulerOrder);
    };

    this.updateRotationVector = function() {
        this.rotationVector.x = ( -this.moveState.pitchDown + this.moveState.pitchUp );
        this.rotationVector.y = ( -this.moveState.yawRight  + this.moveState.yawLeft );
        this.rotationVector.z = ( -this.moveState.rollRight + this.moveState.rollLeft );
    };

    function bind(scope, fn) {
        return function () {
            fn.apply( scope, arguments );
        };
    };

    this.updateRotationVector();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are encountering is due to the way in which rotations are calculated and applied to objects in three.js (well, 3D engines in general). For each rotation axis (x, y & z) a rotation matrix is multiplied onto the object's matrix (which contains it's position, scale and rotation).

Since matrices are non-commutative; meaning that A * B != B * A, the order of multiplication matters. By default this 'Euler order' is X then Y then Z. That is why your Z rotation seems to make sense, but your Y rotation is not what you would intuitively expect it to be.

Have no fear, there is a solution! I assume that you would like your plane to rotate in the same fashion as the camera in this demo where each additional change in rotation is applied relative to the current rotation. In 3D programs like 3D Studio Max, this is known as a local rotation:

http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_terrain.html

If you inspect the source of this demo, you will see that the controls for the camera are created on **line 76**:

`controls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls( camera );`

There are also FlyControls, which may be more suitable for you?

http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_fly.html

Either way, I would start by playing around with these ready-made controls and using your plane object in the constructor rather than the camera.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! FlyControls is just what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

The yaw axis is the up axis, or y-axis in this case, so you need to rotate your spaceship geometry so it is level to begin with:

```
geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX( - Math.PI / 2 ) );
```

Then you need to change the `eulerOrder` of you spaceship so yaw (Y) is first and pitch (X) is second:

```
spaceship.rotation.order = "YXZ"; // three.js r.65
```

Then you need to adjust your keycodes accordingly.

three.js r.65

Comment: Thank you for answering! That's close, but it's still not controlling the jet's yaw in all cases. If you point the nose straight up, then press the left and right keys, the jet appears to be rolling, not yawing.

Comment: Yaw is heading, as with a compass, relative to the ground. You can't head "east" when you are flying straight up. You need to limit your pitch to reasonable values.